# REGEX - Conditional replacement stopping to match when I choose the new string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a lot of developer's name like this:

/Ramon/ /Cesar/ /Murilo/ /Tiago/

I would like to apply a conditional regex to replace every name with just its first letter.

So when it matches `/Ramon/` it would become `/r/`, `/Cesar/` turn into `/c/`...

I'm trying to achive it here: https://regex101.com/r/rTlS1k/3

With no success.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Since your question isn't very clear (in particular what you want to do with your lookaheads), could you explain from the start what you are trying to achieve? I think you need to use a function as replacement parameter (`preg_replace_callback` with php)

Comment: Or something more basic like `str_replace` since you want to deal with fixed strings.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Right now I'm trying to learn a concept to apply later in a list of URLs. Let's create a scenario. I'm editing my question.

Comment: Unless I'm not seeing something isn't just /USA/usa/  and /United Kingdom/united-kingdom/    perhaps you'd want word boundries:  /\bUSA\b/usa/  and   /\bUnited Kingdom\b/united-kingdom/

Comment: You can't find with a lookahead a character that isn't in the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte look at this one https://regex101.com/r/We97pa/2

Comment: @RamonMarques: the difference is that "bleu" and "rouge" **are** in the string, that isn't the case for "t" and "c" in your example.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte hmm I see... So what you meant is that my case is impossible with regex?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ok I got it, just added what I want to replace into the file too. Thanks.

Comment: A regex can't create characters, all you can do is to capture the first letter and to make it lowercase with a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using PCRE based on your regex101, then search for:

```
/\/(\w)[^\/]+\//g
```

and replace with

```
/\L\1/
```

As seen here: https://regex101.com/r/ZDQlEY/1